# Pie Chart shows up only when I zoom in-out

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I've been trying to display a pie chart, with Chart.js, but it only shows up when there is a change in the dimensions of the canvas.

The idea is to fetch some data from a RESTAPI and display the information in a pie chart

I found out another answered question, but it uses Ajax which I do not(atleast to my knowledge).

Below you may find my code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>My Chart.js Chart</title>
</head>
<body>
<div >
    <canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>

</body>


<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var vNames=[];
    var vCounts=[];
    fetch('/Conflicts/conflictsOnAllCountries')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {

            data.forEach(country => vNames.push(country.name))
            data.forEach(country => vCounts.push(country.conflictsCount))
            data.forEach(country => console.log(country.name))
            data.forEach(country => console.log(country.conflictsCount))

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Fetch error:', err);
        });


    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'pie', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
                data: {

                    labels: vNames,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Conflicts',
                        data: vCounts,
                        //backgroundColor:'green',
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
                            'rgba(255,173,155,0.6)',
                            'rgba(146,255,78,0.6)',
                            'rgba(113,255,219,0.6)'

                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderColor: '#777',
                        hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                        hoverBorderColor: '#000'
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Conflicts/Country',
                        fontSize: 25
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: 'right',
                        labels: {
                            fontColor: '#000'
                        }
                    },
                    layout: {
                        padding: {
                            left: 50,
                            right: 50,
                            bottom: 50,
                            top: 50
                        }
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            });



    // Global Options
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 15;
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';



</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw the chart after the `fetch` has finished and you have processed the data.

So, you can put the chart drawing code in a function and call it inside the `then` right after processing the `data`.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var vNames = [];
var vCounts = [];
fetch('/Conflicts/conflictsOnAllCountries')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    data.forEach(country => {
      vNames.push(country.name)
      vCounts.push(country.conflictsCount)
    });

    drawChart();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Fetch error:', err);
  });

function drawChart() {
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
    data: {

      labels: vNames,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Conflicts',
        data: vCounts,
        //backgroundColor:'green',
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
          'rgba(255,173,155,0.6)',
          'rgba(146,255,78,0.6)',
          'rgba(113,255,219,0.6)'

        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#777',
        hoverBorderWidth: 3,
        hoverBorderColor: '#000'
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Conflicts/Country',
        fontSize: 25
      },
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'right',
        labels: {
          fontColor: '#000'
        }
      },
      layout: {
        padding: {
          left: 50,
          right: 50,
          bottom: 50,
          top: 50
        }
      },
      tooltips: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  });
}


// Global Options
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 15;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';
```

Comment: @Volpym the `fetch` is asynchronous. Its callback will be called after the request has been completed. And while the fetch is in progress the code will continue. So your original code was running before there were any data in the `vNames` and `vCounts` variables. Once the request completed those variables got populated, but there was no redrawing issued (*until you zoomed and forced a redraw that used the updated variables*)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Everything works fine now and I understand why.